# Can I use spring security with Spring 4.0?

Tags: spring, spring-security

We were starting to build a new web application and thought of using Spring 4.0. We wanted to use Spring security as well and I can see only 3.2.6 version is available for that. Just wanted to check if it is compatible with 4.0 or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes .Spring Security latest version 3.2.0  is built against Spring 3.2.6 , but it is tested against Spring 4.

If you use Maven , you have to resolve its  transitive dependencies when using Spring 4 with Spring Security 3.2 .

For more information , please see [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#maven-bom)

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. Trying the build right now, will update once done.