# Using spring-4.0 with spring security-3.2.0

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to create a project using latest spring security v3.2.0 and latest spring v4.0. But its throwing error telling version mismatch:

```
211 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]
365 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion - You are running with Spring Security Core 3.1.0.RELEASE
365 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion - *** Spring Major version '3' expected, but you are running with version: 4.0.5.RELEASE. Please check your classpath for unwanted jar files.
365 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler - Spring Security 'config' module version is 3.1.0.RELEASE
```

I know there is version mismatch, but if someone wants to use spring 4.0 then what version of spring security he need to use?
According to this post, spring secirity 3.2 is tested against spring 4.0 and works fine, but in my case its throwing error:
[Can I use spring security with Spring 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896048/can-i-use-spring-security-with-spring-4-0)

[image]

Comment: You aren't using Spring Security 3.2 you are using 3.1 as the logging is telling you. -> `You are running with Spring Security Core 3.1.0.RELEASE`.

Comment: ya thats also strange, I am using spring security 3.2.0 only. I dont think there are other version jar I have added. Please see the attached screenshot.

Comment: Well apparently there is else the message wouldn't appear in the log. I strongly suggest using maven, gradle to manage your dependencies.

Comment: actually its existing project of my company, my task is just the enhancement and maintenance. So cant use Maven here.

Comment: So you aren't allowed to make things easier... Hmm.. However you still have a dependency on `spring-security-core-3.1.x` somewhere.